# How can I write a SELECT statement in which the WHERE condition takes value from the result a preceding select statement in PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

That is my code below, I get this error when I try outputing the variable p_user_id.

ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 84
ORA-06512: at line 84
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

I don't know if I'm properly implementing the Select statement. How do I write the select statement to select ID from the users table where email is equal to the value of p_payment_email?

Below is my code:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE  
   p_amt                   number;
   p_user_id               number;
   p_reference             varchar2(100);
   p_name                  varchar2(100);
   p_narration             varchar2(100);
   p_payment_date          DATE default sysdate;
   p_net_amt               NUMBER default null;
   p_payment_type_id       number;
   p_transaction_type_id   number;
   p_payment_id            number;
   p_payment_email         varchar2(500);

BEGIN
for c in (
 SELECT
    amount, 
    reference,
    type,
    narration,
    paid_at,
    net_amt,
    payment_type_id,
    transaction_type_id,
    payment_id,
    payment_email 

  INTO
     p_amt,
     p_reference,
     p_name,
     p_narration,
     p_payment_date,
     p_net_amt,
     p_payment_type_id,
     p_transaction_type_id,
     p_payment_id,
     p_payment_email

         FROM pstk_payload p,  JSON_TABLE(
         p.webhook_payload,'$'
         COLUMNS (
             amount varchar2(500) path '$.data.amount',
             reference varchar2(500) path '$.data.reference', 
             type varchar2(500) path '$.data.fees_breakdown.type',
             narration varchar2(500) path '$.data.authorization.narration',
             paid_at DATE path '$.data.paid_at',
             net_amt number path '$.data.fees', 
             payment_type_id varchar2(500) path '$.data.fees',
             transaction_type_id varchar2(500) path '$.data.fees',
             payment_id  varchar2(500) path '$.data.id',
             payment_email  varchar2(500) path '$.data.customer.email'
        )
        ) 
       
         where status = 'done' 
         )

         LOOP


   p_amt := c.amount;
   p_reference := c.reference;
   p_name := c.type;
   p_narration :=  c.narration;
   p_payment_date := c.paid_at;
   p_net_amt :=  c.net_amt;
   p_payment_type_id := c.payment_type_id;
   p_transaction_type_id := c.transaction_type_id;
   p_payment_id := c.payment_id;
   p_payment_email := c.payment_email;

   select
    id
   into
    p_user_id
   from users where email = p_payment_email;


   dbms_output.put_line(p_user_id); 

    --update pstk_payload set status = 'done';


    PAYMENT_PKG.add_payment(p_amt, p_user_id, p_reference, p_name, p_narration, p_payment_date, p_net_amt, p_payment_type_id, p_transaction_type_id, p_payment_id);

    END LOOP;
end;

END;
```

Comment: The code seems ok. The error means that the select returns no rows. If that is the case, be sure to catch the exception and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks as if you'd want to handle exceptions. `NO_DATA_FOUND` is what you hit so - handle that, explicitly. You can handle others (using `WHEN OTHERS`) so that procedure keeps going or - if you want - let Oracle raise an error and you'll handle it *differently*.

This is just the offending piece of code, which contains an inner `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block ("inner" means that it is within the `FOR` loop):

```
  for ...
    ...
    p_payment_email := c.payment_email;

    begin
      select id
        into p_user_id
        from users 
        where email = p_payment_email;

      dbms_output.put_line(p_user_id); 

      -- update pstk_payload set status = 'done';
      PAYMENT_PKG.add_payment
        (p_amt, p_user_id, p_reference, p_name, 
         p_narration, p_payment_date, p_net_amt, 
         p_payment_type_id, p_transaction_type_id, p_payment_id);

    exception
      when no_data_found then
        -- It means that SELECT ID INTO P_USER_ID didn't return anything.
        -- Log the error, somehow - the simplest way is to just display it.
        -- Doing so, you'll let the LOOP continue. Without error handline 
        -- section, as soon as there's an error, the procedure stops.
        dbms_output.put_line('No rows for ' || p_payment_email);

      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Unexpected error for ' || p_payment_email ||': '|| sqlerrm);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```